# backward iteration error in for loop using R

Tags: r, for-loop

Still very new to the programming aspect of R and any help is greatly appreciated.

I am trying to perform a backward iteration across 31 possible states (0 to 30) across 20 days. This is the code I am using

```
    ### dimension space
    v<- array(0, dim=c(31, 20), dimnames = c("x","t"))

    ### equation at t= 20
    qwert <- c(0:30)
    v[ , 20]<- 20*qwert

    ### parameters
    a<-1
    y<-2

    ### backward iteration
    for (t in 19:1){
     for (x in 30:1){
      eg<- x - a + y;
      el<- x -a; 
      v[ x, t]<- v[eg, t+1] + v[el, t+1]
      }
    }
```

This is the error I keep getting

```
    Error in v[x, t] <- v[eg, t + 1] + v[el, t + 1] : 
    replacement has length zero
```

I am not sure why, since when I change el in v[x,t] to eg the error goes away.
Again, any help would be sincerely appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Your index is going to 0 because el=0 when a=1. Try `for(x in 30:2)` instead?

Comment: Thank you. That was really helpful. I do need the model to run to x=1, but was able to put in a conditional "el" that made the model work.